# Legend on every page

Tags: best-practices, legend

This is both a style question as well as a latex question:

1. What is the preferred method of providing a legend for about 30 figures having a similar or the same legend in a thesis?  Is it desirable to have on legend in the appendix, one legend on each page, or to repeat the legend with each figure?
2. Is there a way to have LaTeX automatically put a legend on the page if it's not already there?  What if I want to refer to the copy of the legend on the current page?

Comment: If you have thirty figures and the legend is nearly the same for all of them, you'll do your readers an invaluable service by (i) writing only one, fairly complete legend for the *first figure* and (ii) letting a cross-reference that legend be the legend in the the remaining figures or (better still) simply stating in the text (as well as the legend of Figure 1) that the same legend applies to all remaining figures. Of course, do check into the formal thesis formatting requirements of your univerisity: If they require a full legend for each and every figure, you know what to do...

Comment: Do you mean a legend such as a caption?

Comment: @Christian: I mean a legend that is a tabular with labels corresponding with picture elements.

Comment: @NeilG: Well such kind of a legend depends on the figure itself, for example plotting colours or symbols. Isn't it not possible to include that legend already in the figure itself?

Comment: @Christian: Yes, but there are a lot of these figures, so it's a bit annoying to repeat the legend.  I'm automatically generating them now.

Comment: @NeilG: So do I when I have figures with basically the same legends/keys. I use gnuplot to generate them, sometimes with wrapper scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hold this question rather as a style question.

If you have some figures with equal or similar legends, I would group them on one page and have a common legend for those figures. That was the way I organized such kind of figures in my thesis.